# Ratio between the width of the intersection of two identical intersecting circles and radius, when the intersection is $\frac{\pi r^2}{2}$

Tags: circles, area

Or more visually, if all sections of the below diagram were equal in area and the circles are identical, what is the ratio of s and r, or what is s in terms of r.

[image]

I came up with an equation using trigonometry and pythagoras. half the height height of the intersection is $\sqrt{r^2-\left(r-\frac{s}{2}\right)^2}$ where $r-\frac{s}{2}$ is the distance between a circle radius and the centre of the height of the intersection. From there I could work out the full height, then the area of the sector formed from the height as a chord and from that the area of the intersection, of which I know is $\frac{\pi r^2}. {2}$ due to the fact that all areas are equal. After working out the area of the triangle formed by the height and two radii, I found the angle of the sector with trig ($2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{r-\frac{s}{2}}{r}\right)$). In conclusion the resultant equation is (with $r=x$ and $s=y$):

$\frac{\pi x^2}{2}=2\left(\frac{2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x-\frac{y}{2}}{x}\right)}{2\pi}\pi x^2-\frac{2\sqrt{x^2-\left(x-\frac{y}{2}\right)^2}\left(x-\frac{y}{2}\right)}{2}\right)$

I plugged this formula into desmos and recieved a straight line with a gradient close to $\frac{360000457}{302000000}$ but I wish to know the exact value.

Comment: Is the rightmost red dot the center of the rightmost circle?

Comment: No. That's just part of the line that's been separated because of the overlapping blue line

Comment: Isn't $r$ supposed to be the length of the radius?

Comment: r is the length of the radius

Comment: Then $r$ is not correctly shown in the diagram.

Comment: No, this is just a rough sketch. I don't know where for sure where one end of r is. In the sketch r touches both the circumferences, but in terms of the question it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we can assume $r=1$.

For convenience, position the circles vertically, with centers on the $y$-axis at the points $(0,h)$ and $(0,-h)$.

Then the equation of the lower circle is
$$x^2+(y+h)^2=1$$
Solving for $y$, and noting that
$$h=1-\frac{s}{2}$$
we get that the upper half of the lower circle has the equation
$$y=-1+\frac{s}{2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
Letting $(-a,0)$ and $(a,0)$ be the points where the circles interect, we get
$$a={\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\sqrt{s(4-s)}$$
hence the area of the region where the disks overlap is
\begin{align*}
&
4
\int_0^
{
{\Large{
\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{s(4-s)}
}}
}
\!
\left(
-1+\frac{s}{2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}
\right)
\;dx\\[6pt]
=\;&
2\sin^{-1}\left({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\sqrt{s(4-s)}\right)-{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}(2-s)\sqrt{s(4-s)}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Solving the equation
$$
2\sin^{-1}\left({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\sqrt{s(4-s)}\right)-{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}(2-s)\sqrt{s(4-s)}
=\pi/2$$
numerically yields 
$$s\approx 1.192054493$$
which matches the ratio you found.

Comment: I understand you reaching that equation. I only wonder though how you reached my numerical value from it without solving for s. Or did you simply just miss out the equation.

Comment: Or did you solve by iteration?

Comment: I reached a quartic formula by rearranging your bottom equation. I went online to solve it and it didn't produce that value

Comment: Oh wait the equation went over a line.

Comment: @yolo: By the form of the equation, an exact symbolic solution is almost certainly unobtainable. To solve numerically, I used Maple's built-in fsolve function.

Comment: So I'm assuming this irrational must be transcendental then, so does your method prove it is not a transcendental in terms of pi?

Comment: @yolo: I didn't prove that the solution is transcendental, but the nature of the equation strongly suggests that it is.

Comment: Would you say that if it is true that it is transcendental, that it is in terms of pi? And if so, is it provable on both accounts (being transcendental and in terms of pi)?

Comment: @yolo: I doubt that the solution can be expressed symbolically in any meaningful way, not even in terms of $\pi$. These kinds of equations get solved _numerically_, yielding approximate results (but highly accurate).

Comment: @yolo: As far as proving that the solution can't be expressed symbolically in terms of elementary functions, such proofs typically require very advanced theorems and research-level methods (beyond my pay grade!).

Comment: Like Wile's Theorem advanced mathematics I should guess. Do you mean pay grade metaphorically or literally as in- do you work in the field of mathematics?

Comment: @yolo: metaphorically.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a half of the lens shaped lune cut along a central vertical line. Sector angle at center of either circle is $2 \theta$

$$ \frac{2 \theta}{2 \pi} .\pi r^2 -\frac12 r \sin \theta. r \cos\theta = \pi r^2/4$$

Simplifying 
$$ \theta - \sin \theta \cos \theta =\frac{\pi}{4} $$
A transcendental equation this is.. can be solved by numerical methods e.g., Regula_Falsi, Newton-Raphson etc. We get after iteration $$ \theta_1 \approx 1.15494  $$

Draw a horizontal line at mid of lens shape.
Its length is
$$ s/r =2 (1-\cos \theta_1) \approx 1.19205 $$